# How to detect and condition based on hostname

Tags: compiling, conditionals, collaboration

How do I construct a conditional statement based on the hostname of the compiling computer in LaTeX? For example:

```
\ifhostname{mymachine}
  \dostuff
\else
  \dootherstuff
\fi
```

Why: I am working with a collaborator on a document that has dependencies on a couple files that are located in different places. I would like the document to automagically detect who is compiling it and use the appropriate file locations.

Comment: ... see alternative methods in [Printing Hostname in Lua - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621872/printing-hostname-in-lua) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could possibly detect it via `\immediate\write18` but those might require OS specific code  An easier method to accomplish this would be to test for the existence of a file via `\IfFileExists` and test say `~/<user>/.login`.

The test example below will result in the equation being centered (assuming you save this as a file with .tex extension). However, if you change the test for a file that does not exist the equations will be left aligned...

```
\documentclass{article}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.tex}{% Adjust file name here to ~/user/.login or some other known file
    \usepackage{amsmath}
}{
    \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    y &= x
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 7):

In luatex, you can use `os.getenv('HOSTNAME')` to get the host name at least on *nix systems. I don't know the environmental variable is also set on Windows or not. Thus, in ConTeXt you can use

```
\startluacode
   if os.getenv('HOSTNAME') == "...." then
      ...
   else
      ...
   end
\stopluacode
```

or in LaTeX you can use

```
\usepackage{luacode}
....
\begin{luacode}
   if os.getenv('HOSTNAME') == "...." then
      ...
   else
      ...
   end
\end{luacode}
```

Answer (score 4):

At least on Linux, hostname should be in `/etc/hostname`, so you can try to input that file, using the Heiko Oberdiek's `catchfile` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\CatchFileDef{\hname}{/etc/hostname}{}
\def\myhname{myhostname }

\begin{document}
\hname \myhname

\ifx\hname\myhname Blah \else Bloh\fi
\end{document}
```

should print your hostname and uses `\ifx` to compare it to a given value.

Answer (score 2):

I would make it simple and place a short file into your local TEXMF tree or in the document folder which contains a different if-switch command on every host. This file can then be easily read using `\input` or `\InputIfFileExists`. Alternatively let the input file contain all required preamble code itself.

It takes a little effort but in this case it seems to be not an issue. You need to now the specific needs for each host anyway.

---

Fore example the host specific file can hold a numeric macro, e.g.:

```
% hostnumber.tex
\def\hostnumber{0}% for the first host, then 1, 2, 3
```

And then use:

```
\def\hostnumber{-1}% fall-back default
\InputIfFileExists{hostnumber}
\ifcase\hostnumber
  % first host
\or
  % second host
\or
  % third host
\or
  % ...
\else
  % host number out of range (<0 or >max)
  % Insert fall-back code here
\fi
```