# How to include image path that contains a dollar sign

Tags: graphics, paths

I'm trying to include an image using an absolute path that contains a $-sign, the path looks something like:

\\NETWORKSERVERA\NETWORKDISKB$\FOLDERC\imageD

I've tried encapsulating it in curly brackets, and double quotation marks, but none of this works.

I also tried escaping the dollar sign with \$, this led to the error:

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

The dollar sign still switches the text to math mode.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{//NETWORKSERVERA/NETWORKDISKB$/FOLDERC/imageD}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85994/97168) solve your problem?

Comment: @dexteritas, I did not try that, is there a specific reason I should escape a dollar sign with an ampersand?

Comment: @epR8GaYuh, I tried it with the detokenize command, but the dollar sign still activates math mode

Comment: the `$` sign should just work. It would only start math mode if you were typesetting something. Youe "MWE" is not a MWE as it is just a fragment that can not be run

Comment: `$` can be used in the path.  Try creating a *local directory* with a `$` sign in it, copy a graphics in it, and include the graphics in your LaTeX file.  Do you get an error?

Comment: I just tried your MWE on a network path with and I did not have any problems. The only annoying thing is, texstudio formats everything after the $ in mathmode.

Comment: @bene, yeah I came to that conclusion as well, and can't really think of a nice solution to solve. At the moment I'm thinking about adding a phantom image which also has a dollar in the path, but it's not very clean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I set up a test directory like

```
mkdir 'NETWORKDISKB$'
cp `kpsewhich example-image.png` NETWORKDISKB$
```

so a directory called `NETWORKDISKB$` containing `example-image.png`

Then the following test document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{NETWORKDISKB$/example-image.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:figure}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

works producing

[image]

It doesn't work quite as it should: the `$` is being seen by `kpathsea` and generating a warning in the terminal (not in the log file)

```
warning: kpathsea: NETWORKDISKB$/example-image.png: Unrecognized variable construct `$/'.
```

But that seems to be harmless.

The log file shows the normal image inclusion log:

```
<./NETWORKDISKB$/example-image.png>]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I managed to do it for my case as well. I got confused because my editor saw the $ sign as the start of the math environment, and start formatting the colors accordingly. But the compilation did not result in any errors. I tried to fix the formatting by escaping the dollar sign, but then the error that I mentioned in my question arises. Do you know a way to escape the dollar sign whilst avoiding the Tex Capacity error, or should I ask this in a separate question?

Comment: @ROIMaison that would be an editor specific question, can't help unless the editor is emacs:-) actually the colouring was wrong in emacs as well, but I usually ignore such things