# Parse JSON for Dropbox path

Tags: luatex, dropbox, json

I keep all my tex files in a Dropbox directory, but different computers (all Windows-based) have different user names, so I would like to define a command in my template that is the Dropbox path, to which I can append paths for commands such as

```
\includegraphics{\Dropbox/Figures/fig1}
\input{\Dropbox/Macros/math_commands}
```

From [Dropbox's website](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/4584) I found that the Dropbox path can be read from a JSON file at

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json
```

so I would like to parse the file (my file contains only a personal account, but this potentially would need to be specified in case the .json file contained additional accounts) and define a new command

```
\newcommand{\Dropbox}{%path from the json%}
```

The previous question on parsing JSON in LaTeX was about printing the contents, and I couldn't figure out how to adapt that to my use case.

In case it matters, I use lualatex through latexmk.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30617/how-to-detect-and-condition-based-on-hostname/

Comment: I agree that this could be done on a case-by-case basis using if-then statements.  My old method was to just define commands for each machine, that would define \Dropbox to be the appropriate path.  I was interesting in how to do this in a more automated way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with Lua. Prepare a file called `dropboxpath.lua` containing the following code:

```lua
json = dofile("json.lua")

function get_dropbox_folder(filename)
   -- The folder is different in windows and unix/osx
   if filename == nil then
       filename = os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")
   end
   if filename == nil then
       filename = os.getenv("HOME") .. "/.dropbox/info.json"
   else
       filename = filename .. "/Dropbox/info.json"
   end
   jsonfile = io.open(filename)
   config = jsonfile:read("*all")
   return (json.parse(config)["personal"]["path"])
end
```

In the same folder download the code at https://gist.github.com/tylerneylon/59f4bcf316be525b30ab (which I reproduce at the end of this answer, for convenience), under the filename `json.lua`.

Then, you can use all this as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{dofile("dropboxpath.lua")}
\edef\Dropbox{\directlua{tex.print(get_dropbox_folder())}}

\begin{document}
The Dropbox folder in this machine is \Dropbox.
\end{document}
```

Result:

> [image: Result]

**DISCLAIMER** I tested this code in Linux and OSX, and works correctly in both. I don't tested it in Windows and I'm not sure if the path should use `\` instead of `/` in that case.

**Annex**. Code of `json.lua`:

```lua
--[[ json.lua

A compact pure-Lua JSON library.
The main functions are: json.stringify, json.parse.

## json.stringify:

This expects the following to be true of any tables being encoded:
 * They only have string or number keys. Number keys must be represented as
   strings in json; this is part of the json spec.
 * They are not recursive. Such a structure cannot be specified in json.

A Lua table is considered to be an array if and only if its set of keys is a
consecutive sequence of positive integers starting at 1. Arrays are encoded like
so: `[2, 3, false, "hi"]`. Any other type of Lua table is encoded as a json
object, encoded like so: `{"key1": 2, "key2": false}`.

Because the Lua nil value cannot be a key, and as a table value is considerd
equivalent to a missing key, there is no way to express the json "null" value in
a Lua table. The only way this will output "null" is if your entire input obj is
nil itself.

An empty Lua table, {}, could be considered either a json object or array -
it's an ambiguous edge case. We choose to treat this as an object as it is the
more general type.

To be clear, none of the above considerations is a limitation of this code.
Rather, it is what we get when we completely observe the json specification for
as arbitrary a Lua object as json is capable of expressing.

## json.parse:

This function parses json, with the exception that it does not pay attention to
\u-escaped unicode code points in strings.

It is difficult for Lua to return null as a value. In order to prevent the loss
of keys with a null value in a json string, this function uses the one-off
table value json.null (which is just an empty table) to indicate null values.
This way you can check if a value is null with the conditional
`val == json.null`.

If you have control over the data and are using Lua, I would recommend just
avoiding null values in your data to begin with.

--]]


local json = {}


-- Internal functions.

local function kind_of(obj)
  if type(obj) ~= 'table' then return type(obj) end
  local i = 1
  for _ in pairs(obj) do
    if obj[i] ~= nil then i = i + 1 else return 'table' end
  end
  if i == 1 then return 'table' else return 'array' end
end

local function escape_str(s)
  local in_char  = {'\\', '"', '/', '\b', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t'}
  local out_char = {'\\', '"', '/',  'b',  'f',  'n',  'r',  't'}
  for i, c in ipairs(in_char) do
    s = s:gsub(c, '\\' .. out_char[i])
  end
  return s
end

-- Returns pos, did_find; there are two cases:
-- 1. Delimiter found: pos = pos after leading space + delim; did_find = true.
-- 2. Delimiter not found: pos = pos after leading space;     did_find = false.
-- This throws an error if err_if_missing is true and the delim is not found.
local function skip_delim(str, pos, delim, err_if_missing)
  pos = pos + #str:match('^%s*', pos)
  if str:sub(pos, pos) ~= delim then
    if err_if_missing then
      error('Expected ' .. delim .. ' near position ' .. pos)
    end
    return pos, false
  end
  return pos + 1, true
end

-- Expects the given pos to be the first character after the opening quote.
-- Returns val, pos; the returned pos is after the closing quote character.
local function parse_str_val(str, pos, val)
  val = val or ''
  local early_end_error = 'End of input found while parsing string.'
  if pos > #str then error(early_end_error) end
  local c = str:sub(pos, pos)
  if c == '"'  then return val, pos + 1 end
  if c ~= '\\' then return parse_str_val(str, pos + 1, val .. c) end
  -- We must have a \ character.
  local esc_map = {b = '\b', f = '\f', n = '\n', r = '\r', t = '\t'}
  local nextc = str:sub(pos + 1, pos + 1)
  if not nextc then error(early_end_error) end
  return parse_str_val(str, pos + 2, val .. (esc_map[nextc] or nextc))
end

-- Returns val, pos; the returned pos is after the number's final character.
local function parse_num_val(str, pos)
  local num_str = str:match('^-?%d+%.?%d*[eE]?[+-]?%d*', pos)
  local val = tonumber(num_str)
  if not val then error('Error parsing number at position ' .. pos .. '.') end
  return val, pos + #num_str
end


-- Public values and functions.

function json.stringify(obj, as_key)
  local s = {}  -- We'll build the string as an array of strings to be concatenated.
  local kind = kind_of(obj)  -- This is 'array' if it's an array or type(obj) otherwise.
  if kind == 'array' then
    if as_key then error('Can\'t encode array as key.') end
    s[#s + 1] = '['
    for i, val in ipairs(obj) do
      if i > 1 then s[#s + 1] = ', ' end
      s[#s + 1] = json.stringify(val)
    end
    s[#s + 1] = ']'
  elseif kind == 'table' then
    if as_key then error('Can\'t encode table as key.') end
    s[#s + 1] = '{'
    for k, v in pairs(obj) do
      if #s > 1 then s[#s + 1] = ', ' end
      s[#s + 1] = json.stringify(k, true)
      s[#s + 1] = ':'
      s[#s + 1] = json.stringify(v)
    end
    s[#s + 1] = '}'
  elseif kind == 'string' then
    return '"' .. escape_str(obj) .. '"'
  elseif kind == 'number' then
    if as_key then return '"' .. tostring(obj) .. '"' end
    return tostring(obj)
  elseif kind == 'boolean' then
    return tostring(obj)
  elseif kind == 'nil' then
    return 'null'
  else
    error('Unjsonifiable type: ' .. kind .. '.')
  end
  return table.concat(s)
end

json.null = {}  -- This is a one-off table to represent the null value.

function json.parse(str, pos, end_delim)
  pos = pos or 1
  if pos > #str then error('Reached unexpected end of input.') end
  local pos = pos + #str:match('^%s*', pos)  -- Skip whitespace.
  local first = str:sub(pos, pos)
  if first == '{' then  -- Parse an object.
    local obj, key, delim_found = {}, true, true
    pos = pos + 1
    while true do
      key, pos = json.parse(str, pos, '}')
      if key == nil then return obj, pos end
      if not delim_found then error('Comma missing between object items.') end
      pos = skip_delim(str, pos, ':', true)  -- true -> error if missing.
      obj[key], pos = json.parse(str, pos)
      pos, delim_found = skip_delim(str, pos, ',')
    end
  elseif first == '[' then  -- Parse an array.
    local arr, val, delim_found = {}, true, true
    pos = pos + 1
    while true do
      val, pos = json.parse(str, pos, ']')
      if val == nil then return arr, pos end
      if not delim_found then error('Comma missing between array items.') end
      arr[#arr + 1] = val
      pos, delim_found = skip_delim(str, pos, ',')
    end
  elseif first == '"' then  -- Parse a string.
    return parse_str_val(str, pos + 1)
  elseif first == '-' or first:match('%d') then  -- Parse a number.
    return parse_num_val(str, pos)
  elseif first == end_delim then  -- End of an object or array.
    return nil, pos + 1
  else  -- Parse true, false, or null.
    local literals = {['true'] = true, ['false'] = false, ['null'] = json.null}
    for lit_str, lit_val in pairs(literals) do
      local lit_end = pos + #lit_str - 1
      if str:sub(pos, lit_end) == lit_str then return lit_val, lit_end + 1 end
    end
    local pos_info_str = 'position ' .. pos .. ': ' .. str:sub(pos, pos + 10)
    error('Invalid json syntax starting at ' .. pos_info_str)
  end
end

return json
```

### Update

According to the OP, the above code requires a modification to work under Windows (to change the folder separator to `\`).

In addition, it does not work if the `.lua` files are not stored in the same folder than the main document.

The following code solves both issues:

```lua
-- This is dropboxpath.lua
json = dofile(kpse.find_file("json.lua"))

function get_dropbox_folder(filename)
   if filename == nil then
       filename = os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")
   end
   if filename == nil then
       filename = os.getenv("HOME") .. "/.dropbox/info.json"
   else
       filename = filename .. "/Dropbox/info.json"
   end
   jsonfile = io.open(filename)
   config = jsonfile:read("*all")
   path = json.parse(config)["personal"]["path"]
   path = string.gsub(path, "\\", "/")
   return (path)
end
```

Hiding the loading of lua and definition of `\Dropbox` command in a separate `.sty` file:

```
% This is dropboxpath.sty
\directlua{dofile(kpse.find_file('dropboxpath.lua'))}
\edef\Dropbox{\directlua{tex.print(get_dropbox_folder())}}
```

The new "main.tex" is simpler:

```
% This is dropboxtest.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dropboxpath}
\begin{document}
The Dropbox folder in this machine is \Dropbox.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that the paths should use "/".

Comment: To get it to work, i modified dropboxpath.lua with the following:

 path = json.parse(config)["personal"]["path"]
 path = string.gsub(path, "\\", "/")
 return(path)

If you could confirm that this has no effect on functionality in Linux or OSX, I think this would be the answer.

Comment: I'm also unsure of how the .lua files can be incorporated into a MiKTeX root directory.  It worked when I had the .lua files in the same folder as the .tex file.  However, when I tried moving the .lua files into my user-managed root directory, it wouldn't work and \Dropbox was undefined.

Comment: @Shffl Updated, see if it works now in your machine

Comment: Works.  Flagged as answer.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed the issue.