# Printing Hostname in Lua

Tags: lua

Related to [How to detect and condition based on hostname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30617/how-to-detect-and-condition-based-on-hostname) .  Answer in next post.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the question you linked?

Comment: Pretty sure it is a duplicate. The second answer in the linked post has the exact same answer.

Comment: (besides, make the question an actual question.)

Comment: Although this one may (or may not) be easier to search for?

Comment: second answer there uses luacode and a test, not a print.  it is of course based on it and similar, which is why I put the one-liner here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\def\hostname{
  \directlua{
    tex.print(os.getenv('HOSTNAME'))
  }}
    Compiled: \today\ on \hostname.
```

but see Marcel's comment.

Comment: This doesn't work in general. `HOSTNAME` is not specified in any standard I am aware of and in many systems (including e.g. Arch Linux) not set by default.

Comment: Windows doesn't know anything about it either (where it's `COMPUTERNAME`)

Answer (score 2):

The hostname is available in LuaTeX through the socket library:

```
\directlua{
  token.set_macro('hostname', socket.dns.gethostname())
}
Compiled on \hostname.
\bye
```

[image]